# Passing Python variable to Powershell parameter using Python's Popen

Tags: python, powershell, parameter-passing, popen

I am calling a Powershell script within a Python script using Python's subprocess `Popen`. The Powershell script requires two input parameters: `-FilePath` and `-S3Key`. It uploads a file to AWS S3 server. If I pass in hard coded strings, the script works.

`os.Popen([r'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe','-ExecutionPolicy','RemoteSigned','./Upload.ps1 -FilePath \"C:\TEMP\test.txt\" -S3Key \"mytrialtest/test.txt\"'])`

However, if I try to pass in Python string variable, the Powershell script errors out saying it can not find the file specified by the filename variable.

```
filename  = 'C:\TEMP\test.txt'
uploadkey = 'mytrialtest/test.txt'
```

`os.Popen([r'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe','-ExecutionPolicy','RemoteSigned','./Upload.ps1 -FilePath \"filename\" -S3Key \"uploadkey\"'])`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try defining `filename = '"' + r"C:\TEMP\test.txt" + '"'`.  Do the same thing for `uploadkey`.

Comment: I figured out what the issue is. Here is the solution:

Comment: Thanks David. Here is a solution I found:

filename = "C:\TEMP\test.txt" uploadkey = "mytrialtest/test.txt" os.Popen([r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe','-ExecutionPolicy','RemoteSigned','./Upload.ps1 -FilePath ',filename,'-S3Key ',uploadkey])

Answer (score 2):

I know, it's an old question, so this is for those who find this question via google:

The solution mentioned in comment has some risks (string injection) and might not work if there are special characters involved. Better:

```
import subprocess
filename = r'C:\TEMP\test.txt'
uploadkey = 'mytrialtest/test.txt'
subprocess.Popen(['powershell',"-ExecutionPolicy","RemoteSig‌​ned","-File", './Upload.ps1', '-FilePath:', filename , '-S3Key:', uploadkey])
```

Notice the `:` appended to the parameter names - in most cases it will also work without the `:`, but if the value starts with a dash, it will fail without the `:`.